# Where can I find the AndroidManifest.xml in my React Native Application?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps

I have created a mobile app using Expo and get this error when trying to use react-native-maps on an Android emulator.

[Image from Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hq8w.png)

I modified the app.json file as follows to include the api key as follows:

```
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "package": "com.sjroy5.worksideclient",
  "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "API_KEY"
    }
  },
  "versionCode": 2
},
```

Maps work just fine on my IOS device. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file is located at the following paths

> android > app > src > debug > AndroidManifest.xml

AND

> android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml

Just editing the manifest file in the main should be enough.